# Process /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod spawned by systemd has enormous CPU usage

Tags: systemd, overheating

This process seems to call itself and drains my CPU, causing laptop overheating.

```
$ ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | grep "/snap/code/52/usr/share/cod"
  12843    3656 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  4.1  136
   3598    3534 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  2.3  6.8
   3656    3598 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  1.2  0.6
   3534    2182 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  1.0  0.5
  12842    3656 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.9 26.7
   3729    3656 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.8  0.7
   3692    3534 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.7  0.0
   3581    3543 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.5  1.5
  12863   12843 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.5  3.1
   3718    3656 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.5  0.0
   4364    3656 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.4  0.0
   3720    3598 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.4  0.0
   3675    3598 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.4  0.0
   5821    3656 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.4  0.0
   3575    3534 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.4  0.0
   3543    3534 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.2  0.0
   3544    3534 /snap/code/52/usr/share/cod  0.2  0.0
```

The lowest PID I found in the `ppid` is `2182`. That belongs to `systemd`.

```
2182       1 /lib/systemd/systemd --user  0.0  0.0
```

I didn't find any information on what does this process do or how to turn it off. How would you recommend me to proceed? Is there a way to investigate origins of this process to purge it? Is that some misconfiguration which causes this behaviour? Could it be malicious code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realised this process is Visual Studio Code. I didn't think it would be this expensive to run. I wonder why does it spawn so many processes, maybe it's time to clear up my extensions.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251058/random-high-cpu-usage) suggests "Help => Open Process Explorer" to view list of processes and their mem+cpu usage.